# Shrinking or extending element regions in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a list containing zeros and ones:

```
list = {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1};
```

I would like to have a function that takes the above list as input and returns another list, which has the regions containing `1`'s either shrunk by one to the left and right, or extended by one to left and right. I.e.:

```
extend[list]
```

> `{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}`

```
shrink[list]
```

> `{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0}`

I know how to implement this in terms of a trivial `Do` loop, but I suspect that there might be a different quick and elegant solution. Is there a neat way to do this?

**Update**

Here is my ugly Frankenstein (`p=1` to extend `p=0` to shrink):

```
extendORshrink[x_,p_] := Block[{inp, tmp},
  inp = x; tmp = {};
  Do[If[x[[i]] =!= x[[i + 1]], AppendTo[tmp, {i, i + 1}]];, {i, 1, Length[x] - 1}];
  Do[inp[[tmp[[i, 1]]]] = p; inp[[tmp[[i, 2]]]] = p;, {i, 1, Length[tmp]}];
  inp
  ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
extendF = Join @@ (Split[#, UnsameQ] /.
   {{1, 0} | {0, 1} -> {1, 1}, {0, 1, 0} -> {1, 1, 1}}) &;
extendF@list
```

> {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

```
shrinkF = Join @@ (Split[#] /.  
  a : {1 ..} :> If[Length[a] == 1, {0}, {0, ## & @@ Most[Rest@a], 0}]) &;
shrinkF@list
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}

Answer (score 7):

It looks like what you wish is called `Dilation` and `Erosion` :)

```
Dilation[list, {1, 1, 1}]
Erosion[list, {1, 1, 1}, Padding -> 0]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
>
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
> ```

Comment: Well,I almost want to post an answer based on `Dilation` and `Erosion` before see yours. :)

Answer (score 3):

Never forget `ListCorrelate` and `Unit***` operations when trying to deal with near range interactions in lists. This type of array style operations is extremely speedy, effective in these cases!

I suppose this is more close to what's in your mind, right? :)

```
corr[list_] := ListCorrelate[{1, 1, 1}, list, {2, 2}, 0]
extend = Sign@*corr;
shrink = UnitStep[corr[#] - 3] &;
```

---

### A brief explanation in Q&A style:

Q: What do you mean by "extend"?

A: Obviously I mean I would like some place to become 1 when its neighbour or itself is 1!

Q: Then how can you deternmin whether there's a 1 in a number's neighbourhood?

A: Hummm, probably for each position, add the left, the right and itself, and check if it's zero? Well, I got it, `ListCorrelate` handles the summation well, and an extra `Sign` can do the checking!

Q: Well, almost there, but how you deal with boundary? Boundary only has one neighbour!

A: probably imaging some value outside the boundary to zero will be a good choice, so that where encountering `0,0,0}`, we make up a 0 outside the `}` so it becomes `0,0,0},0` and we can deal with it in our normal way! the boundary value will keep 0 in this case, perfect! Also I remember the third argument and the fourth is just designed for this!

Q: Great, then similarly, how to handle shrink?

A: Let me think, well, what I need is probably check whether a value itself and its neighbours are all one and left only this type 1! So a `UnitStep[sum-3]` operation will be perfect!

Q: Well, it seems that there's a lot of similarities in this two cases~

A: Ah, I know, let's write the stuffs together, let's call it `corr` which do all the summation work and the rest do the result processing!

Q: Great!

Hope this helps~

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

**Extend**

```
Most @ SequenceReplace[Append[0] @ list, {0, a : 1 .., 0} :> Sequence[1, a, 1]]
```

{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

**Shrink**

Here I need an appended `ReplaceAll`. Hopefully someone finds a better solution.

```
Rest @ SequenceReplace[Prepend[1] @ list, {1, a : 0 .., 1} :> Sequence[0, a, 0]] /. 
  {a__, b : 1 .., 1} :> {a, 0, Splice @ Table[1, Length[{b}] - 1], 0}
```

{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 0}

Answer (score 2):

> list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
> 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

Taking @eldo's idea, we can propose the solution using `SequenceSplit` as follows:

```
sp = SequenceSplit[Append[0]@list, s : {0, 1 .., 0} :> s];
pos = Position[sp, {0, 1 .., 0}];

Most@Catenate@ReplacePart[sp, Thread[pos -> (Extract[sp, pos] /. {0 -> 1})]]
```

The result for the **extended** case:

> {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

```
patt = {a__, b : 1 .., 1} :> {a, 0, Splice@Table[1, Length[{b}] - 1], 0};
sp = SequenceSplit[Prepend[1]@list, s : {1, 0 .., 1} :> s] /. patt;
pos = Position[sp, {1, 0 .., 1}];

Rest@Catenate@ReplacePart[sp, Thread[pos -> (Extract[sp, pos] /. {1 -> 0})]]
```

The result for the **shrink** case:

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}